# react js button error state metamask connection question

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks, ethereum, metamask

I am trying to connect metamask but the code is not working I am unsure why I also have to format the balance to eth. I am getting the following error :

WARNING in [eslint]
src/Metamask.js
Line 6:12:  'errorMessage' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
Line 7:12:  'defaultAccount' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
Line 8:8:   'userBalance' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
Line 27:7:  'getUserBalance' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

here is the code

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./App"
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Metamask = () => {
    const [errorMessage , setErrorMessage] = useState(null)
    const [defaultAccount,setDefaultAccount] = useState(null)
const [userBalance , setUserBalance] = useState(null)

const connectWallet = () => {
    if(window.ethereum){
window.ethereum.request({method:'eth_requestAccounts'})
    .then(result=>{
           accountChanged(result[0])
    })
    } else {
        setErrorMessage("install metamask")
    }

}

const accountChanged = (newAccount) => {
    setDefaultAccount(newAccount)
    setUserBalance(newAccount)
}

const getUserBalance =(address)=> {
    window.ethereum.request(
        {method: 'eth_getBalance', 
    params: [address, 'latest']})
    .then(balance => {
        setUserBalance(balance)
    })
}

return (
<div className="metamask">
    <Navbar/>
    <h1>Metamask Wallet Connection</h1>
    <button btn btn-secondary btn-md onClick={() => connectWallet}> Connect Metamask</button>
</div>
)
}

export default Metamask
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={() => connectWallet}
```

the way how you use it wrong. either this

```
onClick={() => connectWallet()}
```

or this

```
onClick={connectWallet}
```

You can ignore eslint, it is just a warning.